# How to Set the Background Color of an Image to a same Color in OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-color

I have a dataset of fingernails with different background colors.

First I load those images from my google drive and resize the images to 224*224 as the first preprocessing step.

In the google drive under Dataset folder I have many folders according to the disease of fingernails. As an exmaple: Clubbing

Now I want to add a same background color for all these images.

Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2

#Access the Google drive from colab, we have to mount the drive to colab
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
root_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/Dataset/'

#Access dataet
dataset_dir = pathlib.Path(root_path)
dataset_dir

#Display an image in the Clubbing folder
clubbing = list(dataset_dir.glob('clubbing/*.png'))
clubbing[:4]

#Prepare the dataset contains each nail type as key and list of paths to those images as value
nail_disease_images_dict = {
    'clubbing': list(dataset_dir.glob('clubbing/*')),
    
}
#Create new python dictionary ('flowers_labels_dict') and input numeric value to each label
flowers_labels_dict = {
    'clubbing': 0,
}

#All the images resized to 224 X 224.   
image_list, classes = [], []
IMG_WIDTH=224
IMG_HEIGHT=224

for disease_name, images in nail_disease_images_dict.items():
    for image in images:
        img = cv2.imread(str(image))
        resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT))
        image_list.append(resized_img)
        classes.append(flowers_labels_dict[disease_name])
```

How Can I add the Same background color for all these images in the dataset.

For Example:

[image]

I want to change to this: (Please donot consider about the size. It should be in the same size as above image)

[image]

Comment: please use `#` for commenting, `//` is not used for commenting in python. Also can you add one sample image and required output?

Comment: Do you really need to make the backgrounds consistent? From the resolution you're downsampling to I can guess that you intend on retraining VGG16 or a similar network. Why not see if the network can learn to extract the important features from the dataset itself, including what constitutes foreground? It's likely that the background will not be uniform across all these images, so masking background according to some very simple heuristic may not work well.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON Thank you for your valuable suggestions. Here I am trying to add different preprocessing steps and check the accuracy of CNN model. That is why I am trying to set the image's background color to a same color and hope to check the accuracy.

Comment: Create a nail and finger mask using Range in HSV mode and use it to change anything outside the mask to another color.

Comment: You may also want to use FloodFill.